# How can I clear any pending interrupts in the NodeMCU ESP32?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have built a simple coin sensor with two copper plates that detect when a coin hits them. Upon striking the two plates, I fire off an interrupt which looks like:

`attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt(INPUT_PIN_COIN), Interrupt_CoinDeposit, FALLING );`

This works fine and I am able to pick up when the coin strikes the two plates. In order to avoid the same coin being registered multiple times due to contact bounce, I detach the interrupt within the `Interrupt_CoinDeposit()` function as so:

```
void IRAM_ATTR Interrupt_CoinDeposit()
{
    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(17));
    g_crOSCore.EnqueueCoin();
}
```

`EnqueueCoin` simply increases a counter and returns back to where the interrupt left off. After which, I check if the counter has increased, and if it does, I reattach the interrupt. However, upon reattaching the interrupt, it fires off immediately. I learnt that reattaching the interrupt completes all the pending interrupts. I do not want this to happen. In the Arduino UNO R3, I believe you can solve this problem by resetting the `EIFR`. I'm wondering if there is something similar for the NodeMCU ESP32?

Comment: I came across a similar question that was asked a while ago but was unable to understand the answer to it: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=1836. The answer has linked code but I am unsure how I would go about using it.

Comment: Currently, I am solving this by sending the interrupt to a blank function when I reattach. This flushes out the pending interrupts and I then detach and reattach it to the correct function. It works so far but I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Well the post from esp32.com is from May 2018, but (unwisely) points to lines 365 and 372 in fresh file in master, which certainly has changed over the 3 years since. If you look back at the file's history and what it contained in May 2018, you'll get links to these lines which make a lot more sense [line 365](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/349a77cb557dde34b48fd75c24babcf9e4cec408/components/driver/gpio.c#L365) [line 372](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/349a77cb557dde34b48fd75c24babcf9e4cec408/components/driver/gpio.c#L372)

Comment: If you dig in the ESP IDF source code for where these flags are used, you'll come to the file with low level GPIO stuff: [gpio_ll.h](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/hal/esp32/include/hal/gpio_ll.h) where the functions [gpio_ll_clear_intr_status()](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/b86fe0c66ca17d5907ae26ecdffc9d4eb79cec07/components/hal/esp32/include/hal/gpio_ll.h#L259) and [gpio_ll_clear_intr_status_high()](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/b86fe0c66ca17d5907ae26ecdffc9d4eb79cec07/components/hal/esp32/include/hal/gpio_ll.h#L270) seem interesting.

Comment: You could just ignore the interrupts for a certain amount of time/clocktics after the first hit.

Comment: @Tarmo good point! I didn't notice that, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag instead of disabling the interrupt. This way you also avoid the function call detachInterrupt() inside the ISR.

```
bool coinRegistered = false;
void IRAM_ATTR Interrupt_CoinDeposit()
{
    if (!coinRegistered) {
        coinRegistered = true;
        g_crOSCore.EnqueueCoin();
    }
}
/* ... somewhere else in the code ...*/
coinRegistered = false;
```

Either you can start a timer in the ISR, which resets the flag, or you reset it manually.